# Phonegap doens't work well on retina display

Tags: cordova, retina-display

I developed an iPhone html5 app without actually compiling it. I tested as a web app (with a bookmark on home screen and son on).

I used this snippet to make it look nice on iphone:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5" />`

Everything was peachy but when i finished everything and tried to compile as a real app (using phonegap as a wrapper) i discovered that the above snippet is totally ignored and the app looks zoomed in.

I found a similar issue on [github](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aIIZraoK65VAJ%3ahttps://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/issues/96%20phonegap%20viewport%20retina&cd=1&hl=ro&ct=clnk&gl=ro&client=firefox-a) and the fix is:

> I fixed it by adding this to the PhoneGapDelegate.m on line 180:
>
> `webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;`

But there are two issues:

- the web page is not available anymore (i guess they moved out or something)
- i don't have any freaking `PhoneGapDelegate.m` in my project! The only somehow related file is `AppDelegate.m` or smth which doesn't help at all.

Another fix that i found is [this](https://gist.github.com/510407) which... it doesn't work. I get an error on this line:

```
webView.frame = webViewFrame; // `webView` undeclared (first use in this function)
```

So... Any idea on how to make this to work?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I finally found [the answer](http://www.iamntz.com/2814/frontend-developer/phonegap-is-ignored/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Answer for the lazy add this into your `PhoneGap.plist`:

```
EnableViewportScale : YES
```

Comment: @JeanPaul This is the answer for the older version. For 3.x, try using a library for retina support like [this one](https://github.com/mcilvena/jQuery-Retina-Display-Plugin)